# API/method to create a sub-account in Google Merchant Center

Tags: google-product-search, google-shopping-api

I have a multi-client account for Google Merchant Center ("GMC"). To submit products to GMC, I need to create several thousand sub-accounts (one for each user of the site I'm submitting). Doing this manually is not an option. I can't find any API or way to do this. Do you know of a way?

Comment: Do you want to create a Google account for each user and associate it to Merchant Center? Have you read this explanations http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/base/thread?tid=0a7bf9e5e0a0cf81&fid=0a7bf9e5e0a0cf81000491b8848e625f&hl=en

Comment: @Junior - Still doesn't solve the problem of hwo to create sub-accounts though :(

Comment: Have a go at Google forum, I think someone might enlight you in this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the new Google [Content API for Shopping v2](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/accounts) to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks! This is great. We will probably start using this soon.